# Python class 2.7 binary tree

Tags: python, class

Here is the Class named BNode,

```
class BNode:
    def __init__(self, value=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def __repr__(self):
        return '' % (self.value, self.left, self.right)
```

and print out below

```
>>> root = BNode('root')
>>> root.left = BNode('left') 
>>> root.right = BNode('right')
>>> root.left.left = BNode('left-left')
>>> root.left.right = BNode('left=right')

>>> print root

root (
left (
left-left (
None
None)
left-right (
None
None))
right (
None
None))
```

Q) Modify the Class, so that the result like below could be made.

```
root (
    left (
        left-left (
            None
            None)
        left-right (
            None
            None))
    right (
        None
        None))
```

---

and my answer is the following one.

```
class BNode:
    def __init__(self, value=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def __repr__(self, level=0):
        R = ''
        for ele in range(level):
            R += '\t'
        R += str(self.value)
        R += ' ('
        R += '\n'
        if isinstance(self.left, BNode):
            R += BNode.__repr__(self.left, level+1)
        else:
            for ele in range(level+1):
                R += '\t'
            R += str(self.left)
        R += '\n'
        if isinstance(self.right, BNode):
            R += BNode.__repr__(self.right, level+1)
        else:
            for ele in range(level+1):
                R += '\t'
            R += str(self.right)
        R += ')'
        return R
```

But I want to know if it is the best solution for this question. 
I think there is much nicer one...
Is there some efficient way?

Thanks in advance ~ :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd kill the kwarg on `__repr__` - as a dundermethod, it's code path should be exclusively for handling `repr()` calls, etc. Just move the current code to a `.format_node()` (or w/e) method that has the kwarg, with `__repr__` kicking it off with `level=0`.

Also, check out the `textwrap` stdlib module - with the right mix of `subsequent_indent`, `drop_whitespace`, and super-large `width` kwargs, it might be able to do what you need, but the source is among the more accessible of the stdlib modules, check it out for some ideas on the general approach.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper
http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/80e9cb6163b4/Lib/textwrap.py

Answer (score 0):

You're using a recursive method, which is good.

However, you're not using methods correctly - you don't need to call them as `BNode.__repr__(self.left, level+1)`. Instead, you can do: `self.left.__repr__(level+1)`

Likewise, to create a sequence filled with the same item, instead of an explicit loop, you can use `*`: `'\t'*level`

In general, python has a number of string manipulation facilities which you'll find useful: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Finally, you might like to create a separate tree-oriented map method to do the traversal, and separately write the function which does the work. See: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Python

You can and should clean up your code with these changes.